# Javascript: event.which/button returning wrong value on mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseup

When calling event.button on mouseup jQuery event, it normally returns 0 for left click and 2 for right click.

However, if you press and hold left click, then right click, event.button always returns 2 after releasing left click. This makes it impossible to determine which click was released first until both clicks are released. Same problem with event.which.

Anyone have a workaround for this? Can't seem to find any reports of this bug.

Edit: I know how to normally determine which key is being released. The problem is mouseup is reporting wrong values. To reproduce this problem:

Press and hold left-click.
Press and hold right-click.
Release left-click.
This triggers mouseup event.
Call event.button
Expectation: 0,
Actual: 2

Comment: Can you please post some code.

Comment: it's not clear on the steps reproducing the problem. If it's done quickly (hold left mouse and hold right mouse right after releasing left mouse), it appears that the `onmouseup` is not fired, otherwise (there is a certain delay time between releasing left mouse and pressing right mouse), the `onmouseup` is fired and `e.which` returns the correct value. So your problem is unclear.

Comment: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tn8xC/3/) to try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(document).mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      alert('Right mouse click.'); 
      return false; 
    }
    if(e.button == 0) {
        alert('Left mouse click.');
        return false;
    }
    return true; 
  }); 
});
```